# Design pattern for logging in a scala SBT Autoplugin

Tags: scala, sbt

From what I understand, access to `streams.value.log` is only available within the context of the autoplugin when creating a new task or setting using the `:=` operator.

I'm looking for a good pattern or perhaps some enhanced knowledge on the context of `streams.value.log` so that I can avoid the following:

1. Passing stream.value.log into every function chain, eg.  GetBucket (...,logger: sbt.Logger) =>ParseBucketName (...,logger: sbt.Logger) => GetBucketName (...,logger: sbt.Logger) => etc..
2. Doing something with a global mutable like this

   ```
   trait AWSPluginUtils
   {

       //mutable logger: don't have to pass sbt.logger through every function

       private var _logger: Any = None

      def setLogger(sbtLogger: Logger): Unit = {
         _logger = sbtLogger
      }

      def getLogger(): Logger = {
         _getLogger
      }

      lazy val _getLogger: Logger = _logger match {
         case l: sbt.Logger => l
      }

      def infoLog(message: String): Unit = {
        getLogger().info(message)
     }

      def debugLog(message: String): Unit = {
        getLogger().info(message)
     }

      def errLog(message: String): Nothing = {
        getLogger().error(message)
        throw new RuntimeException(message)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid 1? That's the correct answer, IMO. If you want to cut down on the boilerplate, you could make the `logger` and implicit parameters of your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Implicit parameters so that I don't have to pass explicitly pass the streams.value.log through function hierarchies, eg.

```
trait PluginUtils {

 def debugLog(message: String)(implicit logger: Logger): Unit = {
    logger.info(message)
  }


//auto plugin definition (with my trait)
object doStuffPlugin extends AutoPlugin with PluginUtils {


//in override of set settings

private lazyval settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    doStuff in Global := {
          implicit val logger: Logger = streams.value.log
          doStuff(
            region = region.value,
            .........


//function that I'm calling
private def doStuff(region: String)(implicit logger: Logger)
 debugLog("doStuff now") }
```

Now I can just add implicit parameter `(implicit logger: Logger)` to any function in the call chain and I don't have to pass logging references down 4 levels.